# how resolving the problem: "the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" after dockerizing spring boot microservices with keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-security, keycloak-rest-api

I'm building a spring boot application with microservices and Keycloak for security and angular after dockerizing the app with a docker-compose. all requests requiring authorization, respond with "unauthorized" response

```
spring.application.name=product-service
server.port=8086
spring.datasource.url=${DATABASE_SERVICE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/productdb}
spring.datasource.username=gestion_bien_user
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=${DISCOVERY_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = Africa/Casablanca
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=${KEYCLOAK_SERVICE_URL_REALM:http://localhost:8890/realms/gestion_bien}
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=${KEYCLOAK_SERVICE_URL_CERTS:http://localhost:8890/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/certs}
```

here is the security interface :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    private JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter) {
        this.jwtAuthConverter = jwtAuthConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)  throws Exception{
        return httpSecurity
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(sm->sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(ar->ar.requestMatchers("/stag/**","/product","/product/**","/product/bs/**").permitAll()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(ors->ors.jwt(jwt->jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

and here is the keycloak and one service docker:

```yaml
services:
  keycloak-service:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.3
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres_db
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "false"
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    depends_on:
      postgres_db:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      gestion-bien-network:
  gestion-bien-bien-service:
    build: ./bien-service
    container_name: gestion-bien-bien-service
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    expose:
      - "8086"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_SERVICE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://gestion-bien-database-service:5432/productdb
      - DISCOVERY_SERVICE_URL=http://gestion-bien-discovery-service:8761/eureka
      - KEYCLOAK_SERVICE_URL_REALM=http://keycloak-service:8080/realms/gestion_bien
      - KEYCLOAK_SERVICE_URL_CERTS=http://keycloak-service:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/certs
    depends_on:
      - gestion-bien-discovery-service
      - gestion-bien-database-service
      - gestion-bien-bon-entre-service
    networks:
      gestion-bien-network:
  gestion-bien-bon-sortie-service:
    build: ./bon-sortie-service
    container_name: gestion-bien-bon-sortie-service
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    expose:
      - "8082"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_SERVICE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://gestion-bien-database-service:5432/exvdb
      - DISCOVERY_SERVICE_URL=http://gestion-bien-discovery-service:8761/eureka
      - KEYCLOAK_SERVICE_URL_REALM=http://keycloak-service:8080/realms/gestion_bien
      - KEYCLOAK_SERVICE_URL_CERTS=http://keycloak-service:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/certs
    depends_on:
      - gestion-bien-discovery-service
      - gestion-bien-database-service
      - gestion-bien-bien-service
    networks:
      gestion-bien-network:
networks:
  gestion-bien-network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

and this is my realm on keycloak :

```json
##http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/.well-known/openid-configuration

{
"issuer": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien",
"authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
"token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/token",
"introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
"userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
"frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
"frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
"jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
"check_session_iframe": "http://localhost:8080/realms/gestion_bien/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html",
"grant_types_supported": [
"authorization_code",
"implicit",
"refresh_token",
"password",
"client_credentials",
"urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba",
"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
],.......
```

i tried to get response from my angular, and postman with no usefull results
I guess the problem occurred when the microservices tried to get the jwk from Keycloak
here is on of my application.properties: